# How do I complete remove the draw value on bar chart using iOS charts with swift 3

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am trying to remove the bottom draw values (in black) on my X axis. I tried `self.chartActual.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = false` but all that does is move the values to below the top of the bar. I also tried `self.chartActual.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false` but that hides my top labels.

How do I remove the drawvalue on the X axis using ios-charts?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    let datamore = BarChartData()
    let ds12 = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: nil)
    datamore.addDataSet(ds12)

    datamore.setDrawValues(false)
```

I needed the last line AFTER adding the data.